# How to conditionally render two components or change two outlets when a route is hit in React Router?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have a React application where I'm using React-Router. In my layout component, I have a structure like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import Header from './components/Header/Header';
import Footer from './components/Footer/Footer';
import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';

function Layout() {
  return (
    <>
      <Header />
      <Outlet />
      <Footer />
    </>
  );
}

export default Layout;
```

Now, when a particular route is hit, I want to either conditionally render two different components or change two outlets. Is it necessary to use nesting for achieving this, or is there a way to have two outlets directly?

Additionally, I'm facing an issue with the `isActive` property in my `NavLink`. I want a div to be visible or show when the route is active. Here's the code for my `NavLink`:

```
<NavLink
  to="/"
  onClick={handleHomeClick}
  className={({ isActive }) =>
    `block py-2 pr-4 pl-3 duration-200 ${isActive ? "text-orange-700" : "text-gray-700"} border-b border-gray-100 hover:bg-gray-50 lg:hover:bg-transparent lg:border-0 hover:text-orange-700 lg:p-0`
  }
  aria-current="page"
>
  HOME
  {isActive && (
    <div className="absolute top-full left-1/2 transform -translate-x-1/2 w-2 h-2 mt-1 border-2 border-yellow-500 bg-black rotate-45" />
  )}
</NavLink>
```

but this is giving error `isActive` is not defined. I tried searching for it online, but didn't get anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When a particular route is hit, I want to either conditionally render
> two different components or change two outlets.

You can do that on that specific route. Use a Ternary operator to conditionally render components on the `element` prop. Also, each layout route can render only one outlet at-a-time.

Example:

```
<Routes>
  ...
  <Route element={<Layout />}>
    ...
    <Route
      path="/somePath"
      element={someCondition
        ? <ComponentA />
        : <ComponentB />
      }
    />
    ...
  </Route>
  ...
</Routes>
```

You could, of course, abstract this into a component as well.

```
const SomeComponent = () => {
  ...

  return someCondition
    ? <ComponentA />
    : <ComponentB />
};
```

```
<Routes>
  ...
  <Route element={<Layout />}>
    ...
    <Route path="/somePath" element={<SomeComponent />} />
    ...
  </Route>
  ...
</Routes>
```

> I'm facing an issue with the `isActive` property in my `NavLink`. I want a
> div to be visible or show when the route is active.

The `NavLink` component can also take a function for the `children` prop similar to the `className` (*and `style`*) prop.

```
<NavLink
  to="/"
  onClick={handleHomeClick}
  className={({ isActive }) =>
    `block py-2 pr-4 pl-3 duration-200 ${isActive ? "text-orange-700" : "text-gray-700"} border-b border-gray-100 hover:bg-gray-50 lg:hover:bg-transparent lg:border-0 hover:text-orange-700 lg:p-0`
  }
  aria-current="page"
>
  HOME
  {({ isActive }) => isActive && (
    <div className="absolute top-full left-1/2 transform -translate-x-1/2 w-2 h-2 mt-1 border-2 border-yellow-500 bg-black rotate-45" />
  )}
</NavLink>
```

Comment: Just a small question Can I use Middleware to login users from same login page but give different outputs, for eg if someone is customer they will get homepage, and if someone is empoly they will get dashbord after login

Comment: @Ainz I don't know about middleware being relevant for this, but you could certainly apply some conditional rendering of content or redirecting after login based on authenticated user role(s).

Answer (score 1):

1. To access the `isActive` property, ensure you place the NavLink component inside a Routes component that is enclosed by a BrowserRouter.
2. To ascertain the URL, employ the `useLocation` hook as shown below:

```
import { Outlet, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';


function Layout() {
  const {pathname} = useLocation();

  return (
    <>
      <Header />
      {pathname === '/outle/' ? <Outlet/> : <OtherComponent/>}
      <Footer />
    </>
  )
}
```